# Outlining functionality for sublimetext 3

Tags: markdown, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin, outline-view

Sublime text is so nice that plenty of people use it for actual writing as well as coding. But many actual writers want outline view functionality.

I am looking for a sublime text package which offers keyboard shortcuts for markdown files which provide outlining functionality similar to Microsoft Word (which is a good outliner, if nothing else), i.e:

- show all headings up to a given level, and selectively expand or roll-up a given heading
- (and/or) change shift-tab in the SmartMarkdown package so it cycles thru all unfolded, just H1, then all Headings, but no bodytext.
- 4 options for moving a headline (and all material which belongs to it, i.e. body text and all lower-level subheads, as far as the next same-level head): up, down, promote, demote (mapped to say alt+the arrow keys),
- 4 more options same as above but just move the heading without the material that belongs to it (say add Shift key for this).

Relevant packages are SmartMarkdown which has only a fraction of these https://github.com/demon386/SmartMarkdown/issues/10 and markdownEditing https://github.com/SublimeText-Markdown/MarkdownEditing/issues/171

Real outline junkies need most or all of what I set out above. I would like to offer a small bounty for this, anyone else interested?

Comment: Was actually looking for the exact same thing when I've found your question. I discovered recently remarkjs.com which makes the markdown->presentation process a breeze, and I happened to be working on a really large presentation when my current markdown editor (Whiskey), which support most of what's described, was getting slow to respond.
I guess coding something for the outline based on https://github.com/aziz/SublimeFileBrowser should be fairly straightforward.

Comment: I had been looking for outline feature for a long time, then I found the `ctrl+R` go to symbol can be a poor man's outline. At least it gives a good overview and is easy to jump around.

Answer (score 4):

@Steve Powell , I was using mybase as my main outliner but started to use markdown with sublime for tech notes. I missed the outline view and looked everywhere. I tried atom but it was too slow compare to sublime. I even decided to write one based on the sublime file browser package.

Today I found [an outliner package](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Outline) which is based on file browser. It is still very basic but this is a good start. The package description don't have the keywords I used so I didn't find it in my previous searches.

Answer (score 0):

A real outliner application might be a better solution.

I only know one such application and unfortunately it is on Mac.  It is called OmniOutliner.

I used it and it is excellent at doing all the outlining tasks.  I am not sure about shortcuts support.